# jenkinsでのgitlab webhookのブランチ判別に関して

Tags: json, jenkins, gitlab

こんにちは

jenkinsでビルドのパラメータ化を利用して
git pushされた際、webwookを利用してjenkinsを呼び出しております。
そのときpushされたブランチが`master`か`dev`かを判別して処理をしたくて
判別するものを作っていますが
githubの場合だとpayloadの中にJSONが含まれて送られており、

> payload={"before":"197003c307b5c186398c699845f20aede6a1b700","after":"5f4dbb1c70185a1a0872a4b532e4349c3110730f","ref":"refs/heads/master"

`payload`を文字列の名前で指定することで取得できますが

`gitlub`の場合では下記のように送られてきます。

> HTTP/1.1" application/json
>   {"before":"197003c307b5c186398c699845f20aede6a1b700","after":"5f4dbb1c70185a1a0872a4b532e4349c3110730f","ref":"refs/heads/master"
>   ..
>   "}

上記のように送られてくると`github`の`payload`みたいに参照ができないですね・・
参照したい変数は`ref`ですが
どのようにすればrefを取得することができるんでしょうか？

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: よく分かってないので見当違いかもしれませんが [GitHub - elvanja/jenkins-gitlab-hook-plugin: Enables Gitlab web hooks to be used to trigger SMC polling on Gitlab projects](https://github.com/elvanja/jenkins-gitlab-hook-plugin) の場合は プラグイン自体がpayloadを解析して 一致するビルドを自動的にスタートするようです。こちらの使用を検討してみてはどうでしょう。

Comment: 説明がたりなくてすみませんでした。そのフラグインを使わずにパラメータで判断したかったですがいい方法が見つからなかったです（涙)